# Data structure for dictionary

Tags: java, database, data-structures, text-extraction

I have serbian-english words in .rtf format and I need to extract it from this document and put them into some datastructure.
I know to work with databases but I don't know if it is suitable for this situation. For example i have italic words and don't know how to put this into database (maybe to put inside  tags?). Is there some other datastructure for storing formatted text (bold and italic)?

Comment: Can you focus your question more? Do you want to read an RTF document? Do you want to map Serbian words to English (or vice versa)? What does the formatting really affect? If you just want to map Serbian to English words, in memory, you could use one of the `Map` implementations, like `java.util.HashMap`. If you want this stuff to persist, then using a database (even something like `sqlite3`) would be one way to go.

Comment: Here is example of my file:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/50060017/multi
I need both to extract from this document and save these words to database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the granularity you need in the db.  Can you define a consistent data model based on the meaning of the formatting?

```
class Entry {
    String serbianWord;
    String serbianPhonetic;
    String serbianOtherElementOfDictionary;
    String englishWord;
    String englishPhonetic;
    String englishOtherElementOfDictionary;
}
```

Ideally the formatting (view) and database (model) should be seperated.

But if this is is making the problem in hand overly complex, then storing markup data is a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

this depends if the whole text is underlined/italic or just some parts. If the whole text is underlined/italic you could add two columns like "is_bold" and "is_italic" to your database table. Otherwise I'd suggest some kind of markup (HTML Tags or [Markdown](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)). I focused on the database solution because I assume that you want to store this dictionary persistently.

Greetings

Simon